# search a 2GB WAV file for dropouts using wave module

Tags: python, wav

`What is the best way to analyze a 2GB WAV file (1khz Tone) for audio dropouts using wave module? I tried the script below

```
import wave
file1 = wave.open("testdropout.wav", "r")
file2 = open("silence.log", "w")
for i in xrange(file1.getnframes()):
  frame = file1.readframes(i)

  zero = True

  for j in xrange(len(frame)):
      # check if amplitude is greater than 0
      # the ord() function converts the hex values to integers
    if ord(frame[j]) > 0:
      zero = False
      break

    if zero:
      print >> file2, 'dropout at second %s' % (file1.tell()/file1.getframerate())
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: By any case don't you have an example file online ?

Comment: Which version of Python? in 2.x Use `xrange()` instead of `range()` for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the `wave` module before, but `file1.readframes(i)` looks like it's reading 1 frame when you're at the first frame, 2 frames when you're at the second frame, 10 frames when you're in the tenth frame, and a 2Gb CD quality file might have a million frames - by the time you're at frame 100,000 reading 100,000 frames ... getting slower each time through the loop as well?

And from my comment, in Python 2 `range()` generates an in-memory array of the full size first, and `xrange()` doesn't, but not using range at all helps even more.

And push the looping down into the lower layers with `any()` to make the code shorter, and possibly faster:

```
import wave

file1 = wave.open("testdropout.wav", "r")
file2 = open("silence.log", "w")

chunksize = file1.getframerate()
chunk = file1.readframes(chunksize)

while chunk:
  if not any(ord(sample) for sample in chunk):
    print >> file2, 'dropout at second %s' % (file1.tell()/chunksize)

  chunk = file1.readframes(chunksize)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

This should read the file in 1-second chunks.

Comment: where do i check if amplitude is greater than 0?

Comment: @sam I saw your comment yesterday that this doesn't work, I was testing on a random .wav file here without any certainty that it was the same kind of dropout. The test is `any(ord(sample) for sample in chunk)` - a generator which converts all the values read from disk to numbers using `ord()` and numbers in Python turn to True/False like this: 0->False, anything else -> True. So `any()` will return True if any of the samples are greater than 0. False if they are all 0. That might be the problem - it will only print if the *entire second* is silent. Maybe `any(not ord(sample) ...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple solution to this would be to consider that the frame rate on audio files is pretty high. A sample file on my computer happens to have a framerate of 8,000. That means for every second of audio, I have 8,000 samples. If you have missing audio, I'm sure it will exist across multiple frames within a second, so you can essentially reduce your comparisons as drastically as your standards would allow. If I were you, I would try iterating over every 1,000th sample instead of every single sample in the audio file. That basically means it will examine every 1/8th of a second of audio to see if it's dead. Not as precise, but hopefully it will get the job done.

```
import wave

file1 = wave.open("testdropout.wav", "r")
file2 = open("silence.log", "w")
for i in range(file1.getnframes()):
  frame = file1.readframes(i)

  zero = True

  for j in range(0, len(frame), 1000):
      # check if amplitude is greater than 0
      # the ord() function converts the hex values to integers
    if ord(frame[j]) > 0:
      zero = False
      break

    if zero:
      print >> file2, 'dropout at second %s' % (file1.tell()/file1.getframerate())

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're reading the entire file into memory, which is not ideal.  If you look at the methods available for a "Wave_read" object, one of them is `setpos(pos)`, which sets the position of the file pointer to *pos*. If you  update this position, you should be able to only keep the frame you want in memory at any given time, preventing errors. Below is a rough outline:

```
import wave

file1 = wave.open("testdropout.wav", "r")
file2 = open("silence.log", "w")

def scan_frame(frame):
    for j in range(len(frame)):
        # check if amplitude is less than 0
        # It makes more sense here to check for the desired case (low amplitude) 
        # rather than breaking at higher amplitudes 
        if ord(frame[j]) <= 0:
            return True

for i in range(file1.getnframes()):
    frame = file1.readframes(1) # only read the frame at the current file position

    zero = scan_frame(frame)

    if zero:
       print >> file2, 'dropout at second %s' % (file1.tell()/file1.getframerate())

    pos = file1.tell()  # States current file position
    file1.setpos(pos + len(frame)) # or pos + 1, or whatever a single unit in a wave 
                                   # file is, I'm not entirely sure

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Hope this can help!